# Stacked barchart

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart

I'm having a really hard time trying to figure out how to make a stacked bar chart in R.

First of all, the data I'm working with is from the VCD package

```
data("Arthritis", package = "vcd")
```

Now, I only want to graph the columns **Improved** and **Treatment**, displaying two bars which are the two results of the **Treatment** column (Treated, Placebo) and have the results of the **Improved** column stacked on top of each other.

I tried some commands but it kept giving me an error saying:

```
'height' must be a vector or a matrix
```

So I did the following, but it gave me all the results for all the columns in the Arthritis dataset.

```
arth <- as.matrix(Arthritis)
barplot(arth,
        main="Improvements in Treated vs Placebo",
        col=c("green","yellow", "blue"),
        xlab="Treatment",
        ylab="Frequency")
```

I have no idea what to try anymore. Any help or guidance would be amazing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things wrong with your approach. I think you want something like this:

```
barplot(xtabs(~ Improved + Treatment, data = Arthritis))
```

Answer (score 1):

You may also try `ggplot`. The data should be in a `data.frame` (no need to convert to matrix). Default `geom_bar` counts the number of cases in each group (no need to tabulate).

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = Arthritis, aes(x = Treatment, fill = Improved)) +
  geom_bar() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("green","yellow", "blue")) +
  ggtitle("Improvements in Treated vs Placebo") +
  xlab("Treatment") +
  ylab("Frequency")
```

[image]